# Book about a girl and her mentor whose memory got wiped

Tags: story-identification

I read this book when I was younger. I think it was around 3–4 years ago.

It was about this girl who was training to be an assassin or something, and she had this male mentor, and she had to follow his training schedule everyday. One part of this schedule was playing the harp so the girl could focus and be calm, I think.

One day she had to go on a quest or something, and at the end of the book her mentor's memory got wiped out, but he still remembered how to play the harp from muscle memory.

Sorry if the details are too vague. I don't remember much, but I really loved this book, and I want to read it again.

Comment: Were there fantasy/sci fi elements other than the memory wiping? Also, do you remember how the memory wipe was accomplished?

Comment: I think the mentor wasn’t human and the reason why his memory got wiped out was he helped her too much when his only duty was to train her. Other than this I can’t recall anything else, sorry :-(

Comment: Was it more sci fi or fantasy? Was it set in our world? What was the time period/technology level like? If you remember any of those.

Comment: Kinda fantasy-ish. It wasn’t exactly our world, and the tech wasn’t that up to date. I don’t think there weren’t any guns yet.